# How to keep new line when posting data to webapi with angularjs from textarea

Tags: html, angularjs, textarea, webapi

I have html textarea field. When I have posted data from that field with AngularJS to WebApi I have lost new lines. For example I want to post to WebApi with angularjs string from textarea:

"cm8gQUQgU2tvcGplMQswCQYDVQQLDAJJyDERMA8GA1UEAwwIKi5ta2IubjswggEi
MA0GzSqGSIb3DQE2AQUAA4IBDwAwggEKApIBAQC4VhdOMe7u3tsKykWEOjRG49uD
p39tLAQls2HUnbx4IMmVfsLwE8aEwQ1cVmd80Ms4Et2GEC8WD6q7LRQ1jynqP5m/
l8+pr+RnoqGD6uF4PKf01ZTneO7DMC/yrWk++PvAG/Q7rKPv1mEY+8IGxjRjKX1M
mFh6swc5OzDiD7j4w7I5lp6ouCwAhk1auNn+PQKBSkBl2oGJ"

How to post string to WebApi (with AngularJS) from html textarea untouched?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with saving the line breaks using a WebApi controller.

The $scope.value you are tying to submit needs to be run through the replace method.

```
 $scope.updateDescription = function() {
    $scope.value.replace(new RegExp('\r?\n', 'g'), "\\n");
}
```

This will replace all the "\n" with \n in the string.

The database will save these breaks for future use.